# Spring form binding drop down object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Facing issue in spring form binding.Say i have two models Category and Product.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product 
{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private long productID;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="categoryID")
 private Category category;

 //Getters and setters      

 }


@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long categoryID;

    private String categoryName;
}
```

In controller to render add product page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productpage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView getAddProductPage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add-product","product",new Product());
        Map<Category,String> categoriesMap = new HashMap<Category, String>();
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.getAllCategories();
        if(categories != null && !categories.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Category category : categories)
            {
                categoriesMap.put(category, category.getCategoryName());
            }
        }
        modelAndView.addObject("categoryList",categories);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

I am able to populate the drop down values of categories in JSP page using below code :

```
<form:select path="category" >
<form:options items="${categoryList}"/>
</form:select>
```

While submitting the form i'm facing error 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.model.Category' for property 'category'.`
If i view page source for each option category is assigned correctly. But not understanding why spring throwing that err.. Need help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
<form:select path="category.categoryID" >
<form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="categoryID"  />
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the following change in your Controller's action:

```
for(Category category : categories)
{
    categoriesMap.put(category.geCategorytId(), category.getCategoryName());
}
```

and in your view change:

```
<form:select path="category.categoryID" >
```

The select drop-down will have the category name as the display text and category ID as the value.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work throws err with message Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for property 'category.categoryID';

Answer (score 0):

```
<form:select path="category">
  <c:forEach items="${categoryList}" var="category">
    <form:option value="${category}">${category.categoryName}</form:option>
  </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

or

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="site">
    <form:option value="-1">Select...</form:option>
    <form:options items="${categoryList}" itemValue="categoryID" itemLabel="categoryName"/>                     
</form:select>
```